# How can I download Jupyter Notebook as html, and keep scrollbars on the side?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I produced numerous plots in a Jupyer Notebook, so it shows up with a scrollbar. Like this:

[image]

When I download it as html, the scrollbar disappear, and I get the plots just below each other, making the html too long:

[image]

I mind that it is too long because I have cells after the plots, and I don't want the viewer of the html to have to scroll over hundreds of plots to see the next cell.

How can I keep the scrollbar when I download as html?

---

My client cannot open ipynb files. If presenting it nicely in html is not possible, how should I do it, not making the client having to scroll over hundreds of plots to see the next cell, but still being able to access those plots? The scrollbar would solve this problem, so that's why it is my aim to create a scrollbar.